# Some images not appearing in Chromium

Tags: arch-linux, chromium

There are a few (seemingly random, but probably not random) images I'll come across while browsing with Chromium that won't load. I'll be shown the generic "yep, there's a picture here" icon, but am completely unable to view the actual image.

Is there a plugin I'm missing?

Comment: Are they all the same file type (.png, .jpg, etc) by chance? I had a problem with the redirector extension blocking .png's on random page loads; drove me mad.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any example pages I can check. It seems like PNGs work, though.